Finding the text of the 2019 New York Bail Reform law?
I would like to read the text of the the 2019 New York Bail Reform law. How can I find it?
I tried a couple different methods:

Google: This sorta worked -- it surfaced S02101 / A2726 (in New York, passed bills have identical Assembly and Senate versions) but if you click through the metadata on these bills says they weren't passed. So ... is this the right text?

Legiscan.com: Based on the help page would think bail AND status:passed AND intro:20190109..20200108 would return something, but it has no results

nysenate.gov: I tried the search below, but none of the results were the Bail Reform bill:



Any tips on what I should try next?

The final codified law that resulted from the bill is found in Article 520 of the New York Criminal Procedure Law.
The Senate Bill S02101A was referred to the Codes committee and was not passed as a separate free standing bill. It was attached to the New York State Fiscal Year (SFY) Budget for 2019–2020 and passed (apparently without material modification) on April 1, 2019 according to the New York Times. It appears that the enacted law was Public Law 59/2019 §10-Pt.JJJ, based upon the annotations to the codified statute.
The process involved, i.e. adding a bunch of unrelated bills into some omnibus bill or must pass budget bill, is quite common both in New York State and in Congress.
For example, the federal Corporate Transparency Act of 2021, which mandates disclosure of the owners of closely held companies to the federal government was passed as part of the the National Defense Authorization Act (NDAA).
